# How can I change the duration of tasks in a Visio 2010 Gantt chart into hours instead of days?

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2010, gantt

I am trying to create a Gantt chart with lots of smaller tasks which often last for only 3 to 4 hours. Is there a way of having the duration column in hours and not days? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On the **Gantt Chart Options** menu set the **Time Units** -> **Minor Units** to Hours and the **Duration Units Format** to Hours.

If the rest of the chart is in weeks or months then it might be best to have a separate chart for these tasks. You can't mix time units in one chart.

P.S. If you have a bunch of "that's just a five minute job" tasks, you can guarantee that you can only get a maximum of three of these completed in one working day!